# Alternating cin/cout is slow?

Tags: c++, iostream

To start off, I am doing `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`. I have the following pieces of code, reading a million integers from a text file (`<input.txt >output.txt`):

```
int tests;
cin >> tests;
for (int i = 0; i < tests; ++i) {
  int number;
  cin >> number;
  cout << number << "\n";
}
```

and

```
int tests;
cin >> tests;
vector<int> numbers(tests);
for (int i = 0; i < tests; ++i) {
  cin >> numbers[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < tests; ++i) {
  cout << numbers[i] << "\n";
}
```

Of course, in reality they do more than just printing the same numbers. The problem is, the first block takes about 4 times as long (6.2 seconds versus 1.8).

Rewriting the same code with `printf`/`scanf` takes 3 seconds i both cases. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: `cin` and `cout` are [`tie()`d.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie) Operating on one calls `flush()` on the other.

Comment: Isn't that what `sync_with_stdio` is supposed to prevent?

Comment: No. That breaks the connection between `cout` and `printf`, say. Not between `cout` and `cin`.

Comment: Oh, thanks, adding `cin.tie(NULL)` did indeed help. Well, that's good to know >.>

Comment: @riv `sync_with_stdio` ensures that output to `std::cout` and `stdout` don't get mixed.  `tie()` ensures that any output to `std::cout` appears _before_ any attempt to read from `std::cin` (roughly speaking, in this case).  In other words, if you're interactively outputting a prompt, then inputting, you don't need an explicit flush (which you would need if the output were to `stdout` and the input from `stdin`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`std::basic_ios::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie), in particular these parts:

> A tied stream is an output stream which is synchronized with the sequence controlled by the stream buffer (`rdbuf()`), that is, `flush()` is called on the tied stream before any input/output operation on `*this`.
>
> By default, the standard streams `cin`, `cerr` and `clog` are tied to `cout`. Similarly, their wide counterparts `wcin`, `wcerr` and `wclog` are tied to `wcout`.

The point is to make sure that, in a typical interactive program doing things like `cout << "Enter something: "; cin >> something;`, the prompt actually appears on the screen before the program waits for input.

But in your case, those extra `flush()` calls defeat any buffering the streams might do, thus hurting performance.

You can break the tie with `cin.tie(nullptr);`